# How to get the itemcontainer in Itemscontrol?

Tags: c#, uwp

The UI:
[image]

The Code:
[image]

I want to get ListView control 's itemcontainer , but always get null.
If I get the item from the event SelectionChanged,the code will work correctly.

I can't understand why this happens.

Comment: Instead of using the image, type the text of the code. No one can help you with a picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use [ItemsControl.ContainerFromItem(Object) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.containerfromitem?view=winrt-22621), the parameter needs to be the data that you set. Not an item object from the `ListView.Items`.

It should be something like this:

```
public List<Model> list { get;set; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        list = new List<Model>();
        list.Add(new Model { Name = "A" });
        list.Add(new Model { Name = "B" });
        list.Add(new Model { Name = "C" });
        list.Add(new Model { Name = "D" });
        mylist.ItemsSource = list;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewItem item = mylist.ContainerFromItem(list[1]) as ListViewItem;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks,sir.It worked in my simple test code.But if i try it in another complex project ,it still return null.maybe some wrong else occures

Comment: @大江东去fff  Please ask a new question so we could look at that one.

Comment: Thank you ,sir,but I give up that method.I tried to use the method  ContainerFromIndex in for loop, the items source has 1 6 items,but it crashed  at index 8.Now  I don't want to get all containers